# cypress- run tests with other domains fail

Tags: cypress

I have a problem that when I run 3 tests that every test visit other domain I got this error in the third test:

[image]

it always happen in the third change.
for example:

```
test 1 domain: https://example.cypress.io
test 2 domain: https://www.walla.co.il/
test 3 domain: https://example.cypress.io - here it will fail
```

Comment: its looks like you made an endless loop, could you share your test code?